# Java, convert(cast) Serializable objects to other objects

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

I'm using `Session.save()` method (in Hibernate) to persist my entity objects which returns an object of type `java.io.Serializable`.

The returned value is the generated primary key for the entity.

The generated primary key is of type `long` (or bigint).

The question is that: How can I convert or cast the returned value to `long`?

```
Serializable result = session.save(myEntityObject);

//This line of code fails. 
long r = (long)result;
```

Comment: Have you tried `long r = ((Long) result).getLong()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try casting the result (since it's not a primitive) to `Long` instead of `long`.

```
Long r = (Long)result;
long longValue = r.longValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
long r = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(result)).longValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a debugger and breaking at that line to see what "result" is exactly?

It could be BigDecimal or Long or ...

Alternatively, cant you just call the primary key getter method on the object - I'd have hoped it would be set by that point.

HTH,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try using `long r = ((Long) result).getLong()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should have specified the type of error you are getting ! Anyways this should work..

```
long r = Long.valueOf(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer not worked for me.

I misunderstood the function of `statelessSession.get(...)`.
The second parameter should be the primitive value of the `primary-key` if it is a `non-composte` key.

If the Entity has a composite key you should pass the entity itself (with filled pk) as second argument.

I was confused, because I thought that I need to pass always an entity as second argument to `statelessSession.get` (because it works for multi-key-entitys).